# echo $BASH conflict with which bash

Tags: bash, osx

I install the latest bash,

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0)
```

resides in directory

```
$ which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Nonetheless, the environment

```
$ echo $BASH
/bin/bash
```

How could I change `$BASH` to `/usr/local/bin/bash`, Am I applying the old-bash in terminal every day routines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/usr/local/bin/bash` executable is the first `bash` found in your `$PATH`, and it's that `bash` that you invoke when you do `bash --version`.

However, it's `/bin/bash` that is currently your interactive shell.

This could be because it's your login shell, or the terminal that you use has been configured to start `/bin/bash` explicitly.

To change your login shell, use the `chsh` command.  On macOS, you may also change your default shell in the "User & Groups" preferences (through the "Advanced Options" you access by right-clicking your user in the list).

Answer (score -1):

`which` is a `csh` script that depends on `.cshrc` and thus may be wrong for other shells.

Don't use `which` but rather use `type`.

Comment: `/usr/bin/which` on macOS is a binary executable. It's inherited from FreeBSD and the FreeBSD source code does not try to use `.cshrc` in any way.